# How to Authorize in MVC 4.0 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Basically I want to add 2 view in my project/website. One for Admin and another for User.
I already add [Authorize] tag in my target controller and it works.

After use [Authorize] tag when I try to insert something that time it redirect to registration page and any of the registration member can input data. But how can I specific an admin who can input data in table ??

I watch several tutorial and video but there working approach is not clear for me. In plural site video they use Seed data and write a method in there. But I input data in database. So, how can I work with this video tutorial ?? Because I don't have any seed data.

Comment: You want to authorize the controller method only to admins? If you want only admins to be able to insert data in the form why you let all users go to that view in the first place?

Comment: That's not clear what are you asking about. Do you want to restrict users by role to enter information? Or access to see some inputs on view? or 'how can I work with this video tutorial ??' :)

Comment: @e4rthdog
actually I want to authorize the controller method only for 1 admins. But I don't know how to restricted other user to access the table

Comment: @OleksiiAza
Yes, I want to restrict users by role to enter information. But only 1 admin can insert information and I don't know how to do that..

Comment: if you restrict your controller action only to admin , how else can another user enter data to the table? I mean if only this action access this view how else?

Comment: Try to specify Roles in Authorize attribute. [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")] so that only Users belong to "Administrator" can access action method.

Comment: @malkam
How to create role in project ? I mean its details method or any thing else which I have to write in my project. Only write those lines on the top of my Controller not working for me.

Comment: You can use existing sqlrole provider or create custom roles by extending IPrincipal.                                                  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648806.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can restrict your user on view by just not showing html to him with simple if statement:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   //here blocks that you want to show to users with Admin role   
}
```

Also you can decorate some specific actions with [Authorize] attribute like that:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult SaveTopSecret()
{

}
```

`User.IsInRole("Admin")` also available in the controller, so you can decide which view you want to show to which user:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        return View("Admin");
    }
    return View("User");
}
```

Comment: How to create role in project ? I mean its details method or any thing else which I have to write in my project. Only write those lines on the top of my Controller not working for me.

Comment: Along last decades Microsoft created several systems for role management, so it depends from what you are using. If you're using the last system - Identity, there are two classes: UserManager and RoleManager that help you to add new roles and assign them to users. Take a look at article: http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
@ if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index2","Home");
}
```

hope this works for you :)