# Is it possible to use custom filters based on AuthorizeAttribute in a Razor view?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to use custom filters in a razor view?

For example, I have this working in a controller:

```
[Privilege(Privileges ="AdminRead, AdminWrite"))]
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

But is there a possibility to do something like the following in a Razor cshtml file:

```
if(@[Privilege(Privileges ="AdminRead, AdminWrite"))])
{
//html goes here
}
```

If it makes a difference, the PrivilegeAttribute is derived from AuthorizeAttribute.

**PrivilegeAttribute.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace IdentityDevelopment.Infrastructure
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class PrivilegeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private static readonly string[] _emptyArray = new string[0];


        private string _privileges;
        private string[] _privilegesSplit = _emptyArray;

        public string Privileges
        {
            get { return _privileges ?? String.Empty; }
            set
            {
                _privileges = value;
                _privilegesSplit = SplitString(value);
            }
        }

        internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
            {
                return _emptyArray;
            }

            var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                        let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                        where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                        select trimmed;
            return split.ToArray();
        }

      public PrivilegeAttribute(string privilegeList)
    {
        _privileges = privilegeList;
    }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

            if (isAuthorized) {
                string[] rolesArray;

                var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity).Claims
                    .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                    .Select(c => c.Value);

                rolesArray = roles.ToArray();

                //Assume that a user can only be associated to 0 or 1 role. If 0 the rolesArray will be null.

                if (rolesArray != null)
                {
                    string roleUser = rolesArray[0];

                    SQLRolerecord CheckPrivInRole = new SQLRolerecord();

                    return CheckPrivInRole.Allow(roleUser, _privilegesSplit);

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this not possible? `@if (User.IsInRole("WhateverUserRole"))`

Comment: or `@if(User.IsAuthorized)` should do it

Comment: @techspider Yes I have used that and it's possible, but what about custom AuthorizeAttributes? For example, I have one called PrivilegeAttribute that takes an input called "Privileges", so how would I be able to do a similar thing on that? How can I create a method called IsInPrivilege?

Comment: Attributes or Filters are not Views but for Controller Methods; You may use custom HTML helper methods to do it

Comment: @jbutler483 I have updated my question to focus on custom filters based on AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: It is still the same answer!! You can't do it in Views

Comment: @techspider alright thanks.

Comment: What an `Attribute` is doesn't make sense at all in the context you've used it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips can you please clarify your comment? I am trying to use the Privilege attribute the same way the Roles can be used in views, like User.IsInRole

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question is encapsulated quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582294/how-to-authorize-in-mvc-4-0-razor).

You can restrict the user on view based on security based on role.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   //here blocks that you want to show to users with Admin role   
}
```

You can also handle authorization via the controller such as.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        return View("Admin");
    }
    return View("User");
}
```

However you specifically want the Authorize attribute such as.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult SaveTopSecret()
{

}
```

Comment: I think you may have written this answer while I was editing. I am aware of how to do this using User.IsInRole, but I wanted to know if it can be done with a custom type of authorization, and that is what I have edited in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Attributes or Filters to Views is not preferred.  You can take a loot at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx).

> The filters can be applied at the action method, controller, or
>   application level.

You can alternatively achieve the same by checking `User.IsInRole` in your View and perform the operations required.

Alternatively, you can also implement custom HTML helpers which can act like an extension methods over your HTML controls.  You can check an example in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937128/adding-a-custom-html-helper-to-mvc-project).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, since `ViewContext` extends `ControllerContext`, you could instantiate the attribute and invoke it like this:

```
@if(new PrivilegeAttribute{Privileges = "AdminRead, AdminWrite"}
        .AuthorizeCore(new AuthorizationContext(this.ViewContext)))
{
   ...
}
```

This isn't the same as "adding the attribute" to the view, but it allows you to reuse the custom logic of the attribute from within your view, to avoid repetition of code.

However, I should note that the *preferred* way to accomplish what you're doing is to:

1. put the logic into a separate class
2. inject that class (or its interface) into your controller
3. let the controller action invoke that class/interface's method to discover whether the user has privileges.
4. have the controller action save that information onto a strongly-typed view model, and pass the view-model into the view
5. have the view access the view-model property to determine how to display things.

Comment: Interesting proposition!! Have you tried this? Is it possible to make it equivalent to `[Privilege(Privileges ="AdminRead, AdminWrite"))]`?

Comment: @techspider: I have not tried it myself, but I can't think of any reason it shouldn't work. See my updated answer for how to make it equivalent to what you've posted.

Comment: I will look into the preferred method you have posted, however when I tried with the approach you suggested with the Razor code, I see the error message `The type or namespace name 'PrivilegeAttribute could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` My view is not strongly typed to any model at this moment.

Comment: @ITWorker add namespace`TheNamespaceOfYourPrivelegeAttribute` to that view;

Comment: @techspider That fixed the issue regarding it saying not found, but now it doesn't recognize the "Privileges" parameter, saying that it `does not exist in the correct context`...I updated my question with the definition of PrivilegeAttribute

Comment: You didn't have any parameterized constructor!!

Comment: @techspider after updating PrivilegeAttribute to accept string parameters, I now see the error `PrivilegeAttribute.AuthorizeCore...is inaccessible due to its protection level`...changing it to public resulted in an error.

Comment: I was expecting this :) @StriplingWarrior may have an better way to sub-class it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121003/discussion-between-techspider-and-itworker).

Comment: @ITWorker: Sorry about that, my initialization syntax was wrong. That's fixed now in my answer. I also didn't notice that `AuthorizeCore` is a protected method. In your `AuthorizeAttribute`, you could expose a public method that calls into that method to fix the protection level error you're getting. (I still think you're better off moving that logic into a separate class and using the MVC pattern the way it was meant to be used.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks a lot, I will post the results once I try it out. And I will try refactoring it to the preferred way too.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I ended up implementing the preferred method anyway, although I used viewbag instead of model binding.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've gone down the AuthorizeAttribute route for using enums for setting permissions. It seemed a bit more clear and a bit less down the using strings to define permissions.

So this works fine in the controller

```
 [AccessRole(AccessLevel.SuperAdmin, AccessLevel.Admin)]
```

for example. Now we have to tackle razor. 
Step 1 add this into your AccessRole class

```
 public bool Auth(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return this.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
```

Step 2 add this class (access Level is the enum)

```
public static class AccessRoleHelper {


        public static bool IsInRole(HttpContextBase httpContext, params AccessLevel[] roles)
    {

        var ac = new AccessRole(roles);

        return ac.Auth(httpContext);

    }



    }
```

Step 3. Add the namespace into razor web.cong

Step 4.

```
@if (AccessRoleHelper.IsInRole(this.Context, AccessLevel.Admin, AccessLevel.SuperAdmin))
    <p>has access</p>
}
```

Mmm, I'm still learning c# - but as always I ask myself am I happy with this solution? Time will tell. But a solution non the less.

[Edit]
You can cleanup a little with adding more include namespaces into razor.

Comment: By the time I read your answer, I ended up implementing a version of this. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

An [Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653979.aspx) is ...

Excerpt:

> a powerful method of associating metadata, or declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods, properties, and so forth). After an attribute is associated with a program entity, the attribute can be queried at run time by using a technique called reflection.

So your code:

```
if(@[Privilege(Privileges ="AdminRead, AdminWrite"))])
{
  //html goes here
}
```

**Is completely invalid** as Attributes can only be associated with types, method or properties.  (aka...)

```
[MyClassAttribute]
public class MyClass
{
  [MyPropertyAttribute]
  public int Height { get; set; }

  [MyMethodAttribute]
  public int GetWidth()
  { 
    //.....
  }
}
```

It sounds like you want to encapsulate and reuse your code.  If that is the case then you need to remove most of the code in your custom attribute and put it somewhere else.  For example you could:

```
public static class IPrincipleExtensions
{
  public static bool HasAccess(this IPrinciple principle, IEnumerable<string> roles)
  {
  }
}
```

This attribute is for Controllers

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, 
 Inherited = true, 
 AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PrivilegeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

    if (isAuthorized)
    {
      httpContext.Identity.HasAccess(_privilegesSplit)
    }

    return isAuthorized;
}
```

And you could reuse the PrivilegeProvider in the view

```
// something like
@if(User.HasAccess("AdminRead, AdminWrite"))
{
  //html goes here
}
```

Although using it this way is just a hack around `User.IsInRole` really so it's more code to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.